# VBA OnSlideShowPageChange crashes when adding slide in presentation mode

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I've been working with the code below and can't seem to figure out what's causing PowerPoint to crash on the last line. I've used the same block of code in other subs without issue. I suspect this may somehow be related to the onslideshowpagechange function.

The code runs through the VBA editor in PowerPoint with the following libraries.

[Reference Libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbhAP.png)

I essentially want the code to execute when a slide change occurs in presentation mode. The part of the code that causes the crash I want to add a slide back in.

Thanks ahead of time for any help!

```
Public Function GetLayout( _
LayoutName As String, _
Optional ParentPresentation As Presentation = Nothing) As CustomLayout

If ParentPresentation Is Nothing Then
    Set ParentPresentation = ActivePresentation
End If

Dim oLayout As CustomLayout
For Each oLayout In ParentPresentation.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts
    If oLayout.Name = LayoutName Then
        Set GetLayout = oLayout
        Exit For
    End If
Next
End Function


Sub onslideshowpagechange(ByVal SSW As SlideShowWindow)

Dim oXL As Object 'Excel.Application
Dim oWb As Object 'Excel.Workbook
Dim oSld As Slide

' Check excel workbook file status, if not open then open
Dim file_status
file_status = IsWorkBookOpen("C:\Users\schuec1\Desktop\Peoria 2017 Media\Live Analysis\Live_Analysis.xlsx")
If file_status = False Then
Set oXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set oWb = oXL.Workbooks.Open(FileName:="C:\Users\schuec1\Desktop\Peoria 2017 Media\Live Analysis\Live_Analysis")
Else
Set oXL = Excel.Application
Set oWb = ActiveWorkbook 
End If

Dim sld_no As Long
Dim course As String
Dim sld_offset As Long
Dim teamno As Long
Dim lead_sld As Long
Dim cntry As String
Dim pic_flag As Shape
Dim row_space As Shape
Dim team_range As Range
Dim school As String
Dim time_car As Double
Dim diff As Double
Dim time_one As Double
Dim pos As Long
Dim dist As Double
Dim dist_one As Double
Dim pplayout As CustomLayout

sld_no = SSW.View.CurrentShowPosition

'Acceleration leaderboard
If sld_no = 1001 Then

lead_sld = sld_no

With ActivePresentation
.Slides(lead_sld).Delete
End With

Debug.Assert lead_sld <> sld_no
Set oSld = ActivePresentation.Slides.AddSlide(lead_sld, GetLayout("accel"))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question with sufficient and specific information to describe your problem.

Comment: I suspect that you're right about this being called in response to the slideshow page change event. Try adding a global bool flag variable that you set to False while you're deleting and adding the new slide, and at the top of the onslideshowpagechange sub, have it Exit Sub if the variable is false.